# Recibir un número entero y devolver una pirámide de este tipo (con el número máximo que indique el número introducido por el usuario)

Tags: php, vectores

estoy intentando realizar una pirámide directa y otra inversa, que vaya imprimiendo el valor de la posición en la que se encuentra actualmente y los valores de las posiciones anteriores, de manera directa e inversa, de tal forma que si suponemos que el usuario nos ha dado el número 3, la pirámide debería quedar tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema está en que no sé como llegar hasta ahí.Lo único que tengo es esto:

```
<?php
$numero=$_GET['numero'];
for($i=0;$i<$numero;$i++){
    echo $i."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Nada, sigo sin pillarlo...

Comment: `echo implode(PHP_EOL,array_map(function($i) use ($n){return implode(' ', range(1,($n-abs($n-$i))));}, range(1,$n*2-1)));`

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto la consulta:

Lo primero que he hecho ha sido obtener el número que nos da el usuario, que es hasta donde llegará la pirámide:

```
$numero=$_GET['numero'];
```

Después he realizado un ciclo for, incrementando la posición de la variable $i,que en este caso llegaríamos hasta el número que nos diese el usuario. Después realizamos un ciclo for dentro de el anterior ciclo for para llegar
hasta el número $i y imprimir los valores de $j, tal que queda así:

```
 for($i=1;$i<=$numero;$i++){
        for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
            echo $j;
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Después le damos la inversa,realizando lo mismo que antes, pero esta vez empezaremos el ciclo desde el número que nos da el usuario,y vamos decrementando las posiciones.

```
   for($i=$numero;$i<=$numero;$i--){
        for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
            echo $j;
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: en el ciclo decreciente la condición de salida no se cumple, si al principio `$i=$numero` y en cada vuelta `$i--` entonces `$i<=$numero` ad infinitum